# Example of simple geometry creation in forge viewer angular

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge

I am using ng2-adsk-forge-viewer library in angular 7 to display dmg file in the browser. I want to create a custom geometry on the view.

I created an Extention and added this method. The Extention runs fine but get an error

```
private addToScene() {
     const geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 8, 8);
     const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
     const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
     sphereMesh.position.set(1, 2, 3);
     this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene('custom-scene');
     this.viewer.impl.addOverlay('custom-scene', sphereMesh);
     this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
}
```

I am getting this error message

three.js:35 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. Mesh {uuid: "1CA8B8ED-5370-45FE-B20C-BB6AF483716E", name: "", type: "Mesh", parent: null, children: Array(0), …}

Answer (score 0):

After so many hours of debuging i found a solution
I was importing three like import * as THREE from 'three'.
changing it to declare const THREE: any worked